# How to Correctly Sum Totals from a Table That Must be Joined to Another Table that Causes Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like the following:

## PAY_TABLE

```
EMPLID  PAY
123     100
123     150
123     150
```

## DEDUCTION_TABLE

```
EMPLID  DEDUCTION
123     15
123     30
```

and I want a result like the following:

```
TOTAL_PAY
400
```

I would like to get that result with a fairly simple query and I feel like I'm missing an obvious way to do it, but I can't seem to figure out what is.

For instance, this query returns `800` because every row in the `PAY_TABLE` is being duplicated when joined to the `DEDUCTION_TABLE`:

```
SELECT SUM(PAY) AS TOTAL_PAY 
FROM PAY_TABLE JOIN DEDUCTION_TABLE USING(EMPLID);
```

And this query returns `250` because the `DISTINCT` keyword causes the second `150` value in the `PAY_TABLE` to be ignored:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT PAY) AS TOTAL_PAY 
FROM PAY_TABLE JOIN DEDUCTION_TABLE USING(EMPLID);
```

There are probably several ways to do this, but I am looking for the simplest way to return a result of `400`.

Here is some code to create the example tables to make it easier:

```
WITH 
PAY_TABLE AS (
  SELECT 123 AS EMPLID, 100 AS PAY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 123, 150 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 123, 150 FROM DUAL
),
DEDUCTION_TABLE AS (
  SELECT 123 AS EMPLID, 15 AS DEDUCTION FROM DUAL 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 30  FROM DUAL
)
```

Comment: Why do you need the join at all?

Comment: In the actual query I've got some data on both tables that I need to return.

Comment: Can you update your example to make this clearer?  How will the data from DEDUCTION_TABLE be used in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you need, since your example doesn't make use of the `DEDUCTION_TABLE` table, but I believe what you'll want is to aggregate before you `JOIN`:

```
;with pay AS (SELECT EmplID,SUM(PAY) AS Pay
              FROM PAY_TABLE
              GROUP BY EmplID
             )
     ,ded AS (SELECT EmplID,SUM(DEDUCTION) AS Ded
              FROM DEDUCTION_TABLE
              GROUP BY EmplID
              )
SELECT *
FROM pay
LEFT JOIN ded
  ON pay.EmplID = ded.EmplID
```

Comment: I think this is probably going to be the simplest route to getting the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the join to DEDUCTION_TABLE just to ensure that there is a deduction for the employee:

```
SELECT SUM(P.PAY) AS TOTAL_PAY 
FROM PAY_TABLE P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM DEDUCTION_TABLE D
             WHERE D.EMPLID = P.EMPLID;
```

Comment: This is helpful as well. In the final form of the query I may not need results from the deduction_table, so this helps. As it stands now I do have to join that table to get results.